# ignore space just before string

Tags: xml, string, matlab

I read an xml file and get line to compare it with another value :

```
xmlLine = fgets(fid);
```

which gives :

```
xmlLine =

      <a="true" value="toto">
```

I need , when getting the xmlLine to remove the spaces (here there are  6spaces before the begining)

Any idea?

Comment: Just as a general remark; try `xmlread` and `xmlwrite`; these are generally a better idea than trying to parse XML manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtrim` will do the trick:

```
  strtrim('      <a="true" value="toto">')
```

The function removes extra white space from the beginning and end of a string.